# JQuery post() - handle POST variable with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

so I need to use a JavaScript variable in my PHP code in the same index.php file.
I am using jquery Post(), sending the variable to a separate php file and then saving the variable as global, so I can use it in the index file. The problem is that the variable is not being saved, I can't properly print any php output.

This is my index.php file:

```
<script>
var nameToSend = 'foo fighters';
var request = $.post( "../getuser.php", { name: nameToSend } );

</script>

<div>
<?php
    echo 'name: '; echo $GLOBALS['name'];
?>
</div>
```

getuser.php

```
global $name;
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

The variable name is not printed in the screen, the only way I can access it again in the index file is using the variable 'msg' returned by the post function, but then it's in javascript again, I need it in PHP.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to echo something to the screen at least. `echo $name;` and your $.post call either needs to specify a callback or use the promise that the function returns.

Comment: Try to avoid using `global` unless it's absolutely, critically necessary, something that is surely not the case here. It causes a lot of conflict in the code you create if you start to use this pattern.

Comment: Do you realize that once the page loads, that php code will not run again?

Answer (score 1):

`index.php` is rendered and executed when you request it only. To be more specific: When you connect to http://myserver.com/index.php the code in your index.php is executed by the PHP interpreter and the result is sent to the browser. You cannot play with it anymore.

Technically it's like:

- Browser opens a connection to myserver.com and asks the server to execute index.php
- The server executes index.php and produces an output and since `$GLOBALS['name']` is empty nothing is printed.
- The server sends the output to the browser and **closes the connection!**
- Browser displays the output to you.

index.php is dead at this point, no more execution here. When you reload the page for example, it starts all over again like you're connecting it for the first time, the variables that you set before are all gone.

Second important point is, all php files works on their own, so when you set a variable from `getuser.php` it's won't be set in `index.php` and vice versa.

You can use sessions to share variables accross php files however that's not what you want in this specific case, since server executes php and closes the connection after sending the output to the browser there's no way you can use it  again in `index.php`.

So the correct way of doing it is:

**index.php:**

```
<script>
var nameToSend = 'foo fighters';
var request = $.post( "../getuser.php", { name: nameToSend }, function(response) {
  $('#response-div').html(response);
});
</script>

<div id="response-div"></div>
```

**getuser.php:**

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
echo "Hello $name";
```

So you have to do the computing inside `getuser.php` (not `index.php`), and put the output generated by `getuser.php` into the correct place with javascript.